# (2) motion sensors on the same circuit controlling the same lights are getting confused

Tags: switches, proximity-sensor

I installed (2) Lutron OPS2H motion sensors in my hallway; the hallway is L-shaped. Originally both light switches worked in opposition to each other, so one was only off if the other was on and vice versa.

What I'm experiencing is when motion is first detected, I hear that sensor click...but no lights. After a minute or 2, if I move towards the other switch, the lights come on. I'm not having any problems with the sensitivity and duration of the sensors.

Here are the current settings for the sensors:

```
Timeout: 5 minutes
Sensor mode: Auto-On and Auto-Off (Occupancy mode)
Motion sensitivity: high
```

Diagram of wiring:
[image]

Comment: How are the sensors and lights wired? Can you add a clear circuit diagram?

Comment: @AJN - question updated.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Light to come on if either sensor is activated? Light to come on only if both sensor is activated?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear. I would prefer to have the lights activate if either sensor is tripped, but I could live with only one doing that.

Comment: _What I'm experiencing is when motion is first detected, I hear that sensor click...but no lights. After a minute or 2, if I move towards the other switch, the lights come on. I'm not having any problems with the sensitivity and duration of the sensors._ It seems that you wired them in such a way that the lights turns on only if both sensors are activated. This drawing that you added to your question doesn't help, this only shows how to connect the sensors to a previous circuit, but what is needed is a diagram showing the connections of the two sensors AND the lamps AND the AC power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the two way wiring setup with both switches being setup in series:[image: https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/Toolbox/electrotech/toolbox1204/resources/04diagrams/04lighting/03_2way_sw.htm#:~:text=A%20two%20way%20lighting%20circuit,circuit%20diagram%20are%20shown%20below.]

If you are using conventional switches then there is not an on/off for each switch as such but they have to be set to enable the circuit through a series connection e.g. switch one set to 1 and switch 2 set to 1 (per the diagram).

In your case you are replacing the switches with a switched sensor (which will go on for a fixed period of time then off). If the wiring setup is unchanged and both your original switches were in "opposition" (depends upon your wiring per diagram) i.e. when switch one was on switch 2 was off I would expect the same behaviour with detection by a single sensor turning on the light and detection by the second sensor turning it off. Obviously when sensor one times out that is going to turn the light on again until sensor 2 times out so the behaviour could get quite confusing.

You might be better of replacing the two switches with a single switching sensor at the corner of the L-shaped hall i.e. run the wiring from one switch to the newly positioned sensor and put a plate over the other switch.

Comment: This makes perfect sense; thanks a bunch! The L corner is only about 10 feet from the master bedroom (where the sensor is needed the most) so having only one is plenty.